# SOAP endpoint over HTTPS returns 400 Bad Request

Tags: wcf, soap, https, endpoint, bad-request

I have a WCF service hosted under IIS, behind a load balancer. SSL is offloaded at the LB and then the service is called in plain HTTP.

I got the REST endpoint of the service working but I can't seem to make the SOAP endpoint to display the wsdl page. When calling `https://domain/Service.svc/soap?wsdl` the browser receives a 400 Bar Request response. I inspected the svclog too and the error is `There is a problem with the XML that was received from the network. See inner exception for more details.` which means that it was expecting me to do a `POST` instead of `GET` and to send an XML over.

Snippets from the configs:

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="Transport"></security>
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
    <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
            <security mode="Transport"></security>
        </binding>
   </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" name="Namespace.Service">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="MyRESTBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" name="REST" contract="Namespace.IService" />
        <endpoint address="https://domain/Service.svc/soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicBinding" name="SOAP" contract="Namespace.IService" />
    </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="6553600" />
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyRESTBehavior">
            <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

I tried using wsHttpBinding too but the only different result was getting `401`s instead. Any directions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. I had previously removed the `httpsGetUrl` attribute from the `serviceMetadata` because I was getting an error about publishing a service twice. I now think that error was probably due to a typo and I shouldn't have removed the `httpsGetUrl`. Changing the `behaviors` section to the one below has solved my problem:

```
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" httpsGetUrl="https://domain/Service.svc/soap" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="6553600" />
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyRESTBehavior">
            <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe can you use an absolute address for the basicHttpBinding endpoint. Try this instead:

```
<endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=...
```

To access the WSDL your URL should look something like this: "https://domain/soap/Service.svc?wsdl". With IIS & WCF, you can't override the URL of the virtual directory. The endpoint address value should be relative to the web site URL.